# JQuery won't fire an action from modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have the following form in a Bootstrap modal window

```
            <form id="formCsv" class="row gy-2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="col-md-5 ">
                <input class="form-control" type="file" id="file" name="file">    
              </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                <button type="submit" id="csvBtn"class="btn btn-primary" name="something"> Upload </button>
              </div>
              <div id="loading" class="clearfix col-md-2">
                <div class="spinner-border text-primary float-right" role="status"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="button" id="export-btn" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Export CSV</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

JQuery file

```
console.log("Works");

$(document).ready( function() {
    // Submit form data via Ajax
    $("#formCsv").on('submit', function(e)
    {
        alert("test");
        e.preventDefault();
        var form_data = new FormData($(this)[0]); 

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'src/positionen/getCsvData.php',
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
                var json = JSON.parse(response);                
                addToTable(json);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

The console.log() works.
The alert() within is not triggered and no errors are thrown.

Any ideas why it is like this?

Without the form in a modal it just works fine.

Comment: Could it be that your formCsv is inside another Form?

Comment: Nope. It is just embedded into a modal-body

Comment: Is the modal or the form also loaded by AJAX?

Comment: Not via Ajax but via Jquery.  $("#positionenModal").load("public/modals/positionen.html");

Comment: Your DOM does probably not contains `#formCsv` at `document.ready`. Is your `load` instruction in the `document.ready` callback ?

Comment: I tested `load` with and without the `document.ready`. Both won't work. I use `load`  in the header of the index file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem.

The form is loaded later into the DOM you need to change your listener to `$(document).on('submit', '#formCsv', function() {//your code})`

That way Jquery will also listen to content that is added later by an ajax call.

Comment: It does not work.

The content is added on startup it is just not visible. I load the modal in the header of the index.html.

Comment: And what if you add `method="post"` to your form

Comment: In your comment you said you load it with the jqury `load` function. This is also a sort of ajax call. So you still need to listen to an event like I discribed

Comment: Oh ok, but I just tried it and doesn't work. I changed the listener and added the method but same behaviour like before.

Comment: and the action attrribute?

Comment: When i use `action="src/positionen/getCsvData.php` it opens the php file. But with `method="post"` and the changed listener nothing happens. Only the form is reloading.

Comment: Really strange and what if you change `#formCsv` into `form#formCsv` in your listener

Comment: Thanks for your help but sadly this does not work too. Because the page is refreshing I cannot see if there is an error.
I just used a workaround now `onSubmit="alert('Yes'); return false;"` as a form attribute.

But the error has something to do with the `load`. As soon as I put the modal in the index.html everything just works fine.

Comment: Really strange, there must be something else going wrong on your page. An other possibility is you use the same id multiple times

Comment: `$(document).on('submit', '#formCsv', function() {//your code})` works now. I had a typo... Thank you very much!

Comment: LoL, I know that problem. I dont know if you use an IDE for coding, but if you do not really get a good one, good IDE's can prevent allot of little mistakes like this and will save you a ton of time